# Insert Calendar occasionally returns "Calendar usage limits exceeded"

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Adding Calendar to Google using Google Calendar APIs is throwing exception randomly(not every time or not on specific conditions) while adding calendars :

```
{"Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError 
       Calendar usage limits exceeded. [403]
       Errors [Message[Calendar usage limits exceeded.] 
       Location[ - ] Reason [quotaExceeded] Domain[usageLimits]]"}
```

Limit is not exceeded still there is exception.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting one of the quota limits. I don't know what you are doing exactly but I would start with the last option below exponential backoff.   I suspect that your application is running to fast you need to slow it down that's why you are not getting this all the time you are hitting flood protection.   Example: X number of requests per second.

**Background info:** The following is directly from Googles Documentation.

[403: Calendar usage limits exceeded](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#403_calendar_usage_limits_exceeded) The user reached one of the Google Calendar limits in place to protect Google users and infrastructure from abusive behavior.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded.",
    "reason": "quotaExceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
 }
}
```

Suggested actions:

- Read more on the Calendar usage limits in the [Google Apps Administrator help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en).
- If one user is making a lot of requests on behalf of many users of a Google Apps domain, consider using a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) with authority delegation (setting the [quotaUser parameter](https://support.google.com/cloud#topic=3340599)).
- Use [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#exponential-backoff).